# Removing Java packages in IBM Integration Toolkit (Eclipse-based)

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-integration-bus

I'm working on a project in IBM Integration Toolkit 10.0.0.3 (formerly known as IBM Integration Bus) which is based on Eclipse. I have restructured a couple of Java libraries and part of this restructuring was to add a level in the package structure. To do this, I created a new package and moved the source files from the old package to the new. The next step is to delete the old (empty) package which has proved to be quite challenging.

It seems that the version of Eclipse that IBM Integration Toolkit is based on is quite limited.

The problems I have are:

1. Packages which do not contain any files are not visible in Package Explorer.
2. It is not possible to change this in the filter (Package Explorer -> View Menu -> Filters...).
3. It is not possible to delete packages which contain files, and as soon as I remove the files in the package it disappears from the Package Explorer.
4. If I delete the package outside of Eclipse, they don't show in Eclipse, but Eclipse still recognizes that the package exist. (I've tried creating a new package with the old name and it stops me from doing so saying that it already exists).
5. I've also tried installing a new version of vanilla Eclipse and deleting the packages using that, but IBM Integration Toolkit still recognizes the packages.

Does anyone have any idea of how I can remove the packages considering the limitations mentioned above? Because of 4) it leads me to believe that there is a config file somewhere which stores that there should be a package in that location. I'm thinking that I can delete the packages outside of Eclipse and then edit this config file. Is there such a file?

If anyone has an alternative way of removing the packages using Eclipse that would be even better.

Comment: The Filters dialog of the view menu should have an 'empty packages' option. Note: you must uncheck this option since the Filter dialog selects the excluded elements.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that in 1). Not possible.

Comment: What I am saying is it is possible, I just checked it and I see empty packages.

Comment: In version 10.0.0.3 there is no option to change the filter to show empty Java packages, unless you change to Java view. Are you using another version of the IB or perhaps a standard Eclipse?

Comment: I am just using standard Eclipse, it sounds like IBM messed around with things as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague found a solution. Switch to Java view and then it's possible to change the filters to show empty Java packages.